# Frequency of Natural Resonance with Parasitic Component due to Oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, resonance, parasitic-capacitance

So, I've just performed a lab on measuring the resonance of an LCR circuit. I rearranged the circuit so each time the component in question had one lead on the ground plane, and then measured it's frequency response.

Each time, an oscilloscope was attached across the component in question. When the natural frequency was measured for each component, each time it was different.

I'm assuming this is because the oscilloscope itself has an inductance/capacitance and therefore adds a parallel component to each measurement. I want to calculate the value of this parasitic effect. How would I go about doing that?

Inductor Value: 109.4 mH 

Capacitor Value: 2.116 nF 

Resistor Value: 327.2 Ω

The natural frequency when measured across each component was as follows...

Resonant Frequency of Inductor: 10.1kHz 

Resonant Frequency of Capacitor: 10.075kHz 

Resonant Frequency of Resistor: 10.425kHz

Comment: schematics please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RLC_series_circuit_v1.svg

Comment: Just a simple series LCR circuit. But measuring the natural frequency across each component.

Comment: What you're measuring each time is the resonant frequency of the entire circuit, not of the individual components. Resistors don't have resonant frequencies, at least not in the 10kHz range. The input impedance of a scope is usually written on it, and it is typically 1Meg||20pF.

Comment: I know. But by adding the oscilloscope across each component, I'm adding on additional circuitry that is changing the resonant frequency. The oscilloscope is constituting a parallel impedance with each component as I'm measuring the resonant frequency. I want to be able to calculate the effective impedance from the information given.

Comment: It's called digital o-scope aliasing - that's my guess.

Comment: It is constituting an additional impedance in parallel with both the component being measured and the series sum of the other two components, actually. If you take that into account I don't see anything startling here that needs further explanation.